# Расставить знаки препинания и определить синтаксическую роль однородных членов предложения

Tags: и, пунктуация, синтаксис

Учитель музыки умеет играть: на пианино, на аккордеоне, на баяне на разных музыкальных инструментах.

Comment: @Инна78, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось, либо предложите свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала найдите обобщающее слово. Какая роль будет у него, такая же будет и у однородных членов

Answer (score 1):

Учитель музыки умеет играть на пианино, на аккордеоне, на баяне - на разных музыкальных инструментах.